# transmission-remote commands are erroring with Unexpected response: <h1>401: Unauthorized</h1>Unauthorized User: deflate, gzip

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, transmission

I'm running the latest Raspbian distribution and just installed the `transmission` packages.

However, whenever I run a `transmission-remote` command - say, to alter some base configurations - I keep getting the same error:

```
$ transmission-remote -DU -c required -p 9091 -w ~/torrents
Unexpected response: <h1>401: Unauthorized</h1>Unauthorized User: deflate, gzip
```

I can't find any good docs or tutorials out there to troubleshoot with, and I suspect I missed out on a step in the initial setup process which has resulted in this error. I'll already tried setting a username/password, i.e.

```
$ transmission-remote --auth myusername:mypassword
```

which succeeded, but it's still throwing the same "Unexpected response" error for all other commands.

Starting `transmission-daemon` doesn't work either:

```
$ service transmission-daemon start
[....] Starting bittorrent daemon: transmission-daemonstart-stop-daemon: unable to set gid to 110 (Operation not permitted)
 failed!
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this might be happening?

Answer (score 33):

It happened the same thing with me, what I did:

First off, remove all transmission in your distro;

```
apt-get remove transmission-daemon
```

Second,  obvious, install again transmission, but You need to install transmission-daemon tand the packages like transmission-remote, that's what you will use.

```
apt-get install transmission-daemon
```

Stop the process:

```
/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop
```

Desactived the AUTH:

```
nano /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
```

edit this line:

```
rpc-authentication-required: false
```

Restart the process:

```
/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon restart/start
```

Execute this:

```
transmission-remote -l
```

If it work, none message will be shown. Now, you use a magnet link for test:

```
transmission-remote -a 'Magnet link'
```

Success message:

```
localhost:9091/transmission/rpc/ responded: "success"
```

Links:

http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/setting-up-transmission-remote-gui-in.html
https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki

Comment: Still not working :( When I run `sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon restart`, I get an `[ ok ] Restarting bittorrent daemon: transmission-daemon.`. 

But running `transmission-remote -l` still gives me the same `Unexpected response...` error.

Comment: Ah, I managed to work it out. It turns out [you have to stop `transmission-daemon` before editing the file](http://superuser.com/questions/113649/how-do-you-set-a-password-for-transmission-daemon-the-bittorrent-client-server), otherwise it will overwrite the file when you restart it.

Comment: Yeah, aahh.. First you need stop the transmission and after rewrite the file right? Do u did it?! got it? What's happened now?

Comment: Yup, I got it to work in the end. I've just suggested an edit to your answer :)

Comment: btw, you just need to reload. No need to restart.

Comment: transmission has started but it is stuck at 0% download

Comment: do not restart the service, otherwise the configuration will be reset

Answer (score 22):

transmission-remote --auth myusername:mypassword -l

this worked for me... just all in one line... log in plus your command...

Answer (score 8):

Note that `--auth` has to be before other options - not made obvious in the documentation or command-line help!

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but I did the same silly thing

Make note of the "sudo"

```
sudo service transmission-daemon stop
```

edit your file settings.json file

```
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

Also you have to use the --auth on every command so in your case you would put

```
transmission-remote --auth myusername:mypassword -DU -c required -p 9091 -w ~/torrents
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you can just start it like:

```
transmission-daemon --no-auth
```

But make sure you stop it prior to running the command above. To stop it:

```
/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop
```

Of course, now everybody in your network can access your daemon, so make sure you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

this tutorial for transmission command

to download torrent link

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -a eos-amd64-amd64-id-3.1.7-iso.torrent
```

to limit upload 5 kB/s

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -u 5
```

for limit download 10MB/s

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -d 10000
```

to check config transmission

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -si
```

to check current session/status torrent

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -st
```

Answer (score 0):

`transmission-remote 127.0.0.1:9091 --auth=a:b {-l} {options}`

**SOURCE:**

- Bad behaviour when transmission-remote authentication fails
- https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/174